# Why is std::cmatch slower than std::smatch here?

Tags: c++, c++11, matching

I generate a long random string first:

```cpp
const int length = 100000;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);
std::default_random_engine engine{1}; // set 1 as seed

// Just for test usage, not optimal. 
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) // random abc
    a.push_back('a' + distribution(engine));
std::regex r{ "abc" };
```

Then I use `std::smatch` and `std::cmatch` separately and benchmark them:

```cpp
std::smatch m;
std::string a0 = a;
int result = 0; // to disable optimization.

while (std::regex_search(a0, m, r))
{
    a0 = m.suffix();
    result += static_cast<int>(a0[0]);
}
return result;
```

```cpp
std::cmatch m;
const char* currBegin = a.c_str();
int result = 0;

while (std::regex_search(currBegin, m, r))
{
    // For practical use in the future.
    std::string_view v(m[0].first, m[0].second - m[0].first);
    currBegin = m.suffix().first;
    result += static_cast<int>(*currBegin);
}
return result;
```

The `cmatch` one is slower than the `smatch` one by about five times; why?

Notice that I use `BENCHMARK` of Catch2 to get the evaluation, with msvc 19.29, release mode and C++ standard as c++20.

Comment: The fragment using `smatch` does a lot copying, in `a0 = m.suffix();`. The other fragment works entirely in place, with no copying. The difference you measure is the time spent copying `O(n^2)` bytes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That will make `smatch` slower than `cmatch`, rather than `cmatch` slower than `smatch`.

Comment: Yes. Are you sure you are reading your results the right way round? Show a [mcve], complete with the parts doing the measurements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I'm pretty sure. If you can use Catch2, you may copy three fragments in a `TEST_CASE` with the last two in two `BENCHMARK`s separately, then you will get the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I read the source code of `std::regex_search` and I find that providing `const char*` to `std::regex_search` will cause a `strlen`-like operation first. So I get the expected result after I change the following line:

```cpp
while (std::regex_search(currBegin, m, r))
```

to

```cpp
while (std::regex_search(currBegin, currEnd, m, r))
```

where `currEnd = currBegin + a.size()`. With an indicator of `end`, the `strlen`-like operation is omitted and I get a 50% speedup in `std::cmatch`. Counting the valid characters over and over again drags the whole process.